# unity iOS build AppLovinSDK.h' file not found error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build my project project on IOS but every-time I try to build I get this error message.

/Users/usename/Desktop/buildMaster/Libraries/MaxSdk/AppLovin/Plugins/iOS/MAUnityAdManager.h:7:9: 'AppLovinSDK/AppLovinSDK.h' file not found

I read that it might be a problem with cocoapods so I tried to reinstall but it does not seem to work.
I also tried to reinstall Xcode but still nothing work

my version cocoapods  is the  1.8.4
the unity version is 2020.2.2f1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem

-I moved to my build folder
-I uninstalled cocoapod 1.8.4
-I installed brew
-with brew I installed cocoapod
-I deleted the workspace file in my build folder
-I runed install --repo-update
-and finally I built it and it worked !